# iPhone app: use max screen size when run on iPad

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone app with the screen layout designed for iPhone 4, 5 & 6 screen sizes. It isn't designed for the iPad screen. When the app is run on an iPad it looks as if the iPhone 4 screen size/layout is being used. Is there way to make it use the iPhone 6 layout instead, which would look much better on the large screen of an iPad?

Comment: Change the app from an iPhone only app to a Universal app and change your interfaces so they fit all iPad screen sizes?

Comment: Could you please provide screenshots of what does your UI look like now on an iPad?

Answer (score 2):

If your app doesn't need design changes for the bigger screen, you can just make it a universal app, that is an iPhone + iPad app. If your app runs fine on an iPhone 6+ in full size, then there is a good chance it runs fine on an iPad as well.

Unfortunately Apple only supports scaling 3.5" screen to the full iPad screen size, not scaling an iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+ screen.